# Can't set the properties for the next view using prepareForSegue: sender:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I'm using Objective-C. I set a segue from a table view cell to a new view controller, and I want to set the properties for the new view controller using this method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"detail"]){
        if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[detailViewController class]]){
            detailViewController *detail = (detailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            detail.label.text = @"QQQQQ";
    }
}
```

I've set the segue's identifier to @"detail" already, and also connected the label code with the view controller in storyboard. But when I run this in my simulator, the label would never change.

Comment: are you synthesize your label in detailViewController

Answer (score 0):

at the time when `prepareForSegue` is called the destinationviewcontroller's outlets are not set yet.

what you have to do is create a property in your `detailViewController` class like

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *detailText;
```

then in `prepareForSegue`:

```
detailViewController *detail = (detailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
detail.detailText = @"QQQQQ";
```

and in your `detailViewController`s `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.label.text = self.detailText;
```